# Defective SD card or not? CHKDSK contradicts itself in scan report

Tags: sd-card, chkdsk, bad-sectors, defective-hardware

Scans of a SD card in Windows PC lead to chains of **clusters with similar numbers**. Does this point to decfective SD card rather than to other possible causes (bad card reader, problems with flashcard reader driver or with disruptive apps)?

```
chkdsk E: /f /offlinescanandfix /r
------------------- I'll Keep only substantial lines here. --------------------
Windows is verifying file allocations...
Windows replaced bad clusters in file \Android\data\com.cleanmaster.mguard\files
of name 1.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file \.android_secure\com.booking.forsamsung-2.asec
of name 57251.
------------------- I'll leave out file names now. --------------------
of name 57252.
of name 57254.
of name 57255.
of name 60913.
of name 60229.
of name 60230.
of name 61026.
of name 61028.
of name 61029.
```

One month later, after new series of Android system-wide crashes ...similar numbers again:

```
of name 57254.   <----- exact match - this one was listed before
of name 59843.
of name 60226.
of name 60227.
of name 60228.
of name 60231.
of name 60232.
of name 60233.
of name 60235.
of name 60236.
```

The puzzling thing is that `0 KB in bad sectors` is always reported at the end of each scan:

```
192219136 KB total disk space.
 62334336 KB in 18750 files.
   321664 KB in 2510 indexes.
        0 KB in bad sectors.   <--------------
      384 KB in use by the system.
129562752 KB available on disk.
```

If the card was defective, why 0 KB is reported? Moreover, values of rows 2-6 sum up to total disk space in row 1. This would indicate that the card is NOT considered defective.

Could it be a software issue (crash during write) causing this weird ?

Comment: `chkdsk` tells you nothing about the underlying hardware of the disk on a modern wear-levelled or obfuscated flash-transition layer device. All it tells you is that the ***filesystem*** that sits on top the block device presented by the flash controller is "fine".   If you are having trouble with the card then format it and reinstall, if you continue to have problems then replace it. Your original question was mostly about a broken card making Android fail, all that is left is a broken card.

Comment: @Mokubai – what about marking bad sectors on scan? Isn't it done any more with memory cards?

Comment: It might be, but with "intelligent" wear levelling how would any one filesystem block map to a physical block to be able to mark it as "bad" at the filesystem level? What the filesystem sees is a "best case" and lacking tools to directly query the flash that is all you get. Unless you spent a fortune an desperately want the card to work the best course is simply to replace it.

Comment: @Mokubai – true with that marking, thank you.